# Flutter how to get data from async function

Tags: asynchronous, flutter, android-sqlite

I am having extreme difficulty in handling this. I call an async function that will get some info from SQLite but I can't seem to get it. It just renders a empty screen in which should be a `listview`.

```dart
List allItems = new List();

Future<void> pegaDados() async {
    var itens = await geraCardapio();
      
    for (var i = 0; i < itens.length; i++) {
        print((itens[i].toMap()));
        allItems.add(itens[i].toMap());
    }
}

print(pegaDados());

return ListView.builder(
    itemCount: allItems.length,
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return ListTile(
            leading: Image.asset("assets/"+ allItems[index]['imagem'], fit: BoxFit.contain,),
            title: Text(allItems[index]['pedido']),
            trailing: Text(allItems[index]['valor']),
        );
    },
);
```

Thank you very much.

I managed to get the solution, thanks to both people who answered the question (using both solutions I managed to get this little frankenstein)

```
Future<dynamic> pegaDados() async {
    var allItems = await geraCardapio();

    return allItems.map((allItems) => allItems.toMap());
}

return FutureBuilder(
    future: pegaDados(),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
            print(snapshot.data);
            var objeto = [];

            for (var i in snapshot.data) {
                objeto.add(i);
            }
              
            print(objeto);
            return Container(
                child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: objeto.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return ListTile(
                        leading: Image.asset("assets/"+ objeto[index]['imagem'], fit: BoxFit.contain),
                        title: Text(objeto[index]['pedido']),
                        trailing: Text(objeto[index]['valor'].toString()),
                    );
                },
            ),
        );
    } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
        throw snapshot.error;
    } else {
        return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
    }
});

thanks to [Mohammad Assem Nasser][1] and [Eliya Cohen][2] for the help!

  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/users/11542171/mohammad-assem-nasser
  [2]: https://stackoverflow.com/users/1860540/eliya-cohen
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should first understand what is `Future` operations (`Future` function in your case).  Future operations are the operations which take time to perform and return the result later. To handle this problem, we use **Asynchronous functions**.

**Asynchronous Function** let your program continue other operations while the current operation is being performed. Dart uses `Future` objects (Futures) to represent the results of **asynchronous** operations. To handle these operations, we can use **async/await**, but it is not possible to integrate async and await on widgets. So it is quite tricky to handle futures in widgets. To solve this problem flutter provided a widget called `FutureBuilder`.

In `FutureBuilder`, it calls the **Future function** to wait for the result, and as soon as it produces the result it calls the **builder function** where we build the widget.

Here is how it should be:

```
class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  List allItems = new List();

  Future<List> pegaDados() async{
    var items = await geraCardapio(); // TODO: Add this function to this class

    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
      print((items[i].toMap()));
      allItems.add(items[i].toMap());
    }
  return items;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(title: Text('Demo')),
      body: FutureBuilder(
        future: pegaDados(),
        builder: (context, snapshot){
          if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done){
            return Container(
                child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return ListTile(
                  leading: Image.asset("assets/"+ snapshot.data[index]['imagem'], fit: BoxFit.contain,),
                  title: Text(snapshot.data[index]['pedido']),
                  trailing: Text(snapshot.data[index]['valor']),
                );
              },
                ),
            );
          }
          else if(snapshot.hasError){
            throw snapshot.error;
          }
          else{
            return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here is the [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ek8ZPdWj4Qo) to a short video that will explain `FutureBuilder` in a concise way.

Comment: just tried your solution too and the error was this one "MappedListIterable<CardapioLista, Map<String, dynamic>>' has no instance method '[]'"

Comment: print snapshot.data and tell me what you see

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure how your widget tree looks like, but I'm assuming `ListView` is being built simultaneously with `pegaDados`. What you're looking for is a `FutureBuilder`:

```
Future<dynamic> pegaDados() async{
  var items = await geraCardapio();

  return items.map((item) => item.toMap());
}

...
FutureBuilder<dynamic>(
  future: pegaDados(),
  builder: (BuilderContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
    switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
      case ConnectionState.none:
        return Text('Uninitialized');
      case ConnectionState.active:
      case ConnectionState.waiting:
        return Text('Awaiting result...');
      case ConnectionState.done:

        if (snapshot.hasError)
          throw snapshot.error;

        //
        // Place here your ListView.
        //
    }
    return null; // unreachable
  }
```

Comment: what i can replace the 'BuilderContext' with? My classes are as StatelessWidgets

Comment: here is the error ''The argument type 'StatelessWidget Function(CardapioList, AsyncSnapshot<dynamic>)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Widget Function(BuildContext, AsyncSnapshot<dynamic>)''

Comment: Each widget whether it's stateful or stateless has a `build` method with `context`, so just pass this context to the FutureBuilder.

Comment: A red screen and yellow letters appeared "a build function returned null"

Comment: @VitorAraújo you probably forgot to `return`.

Comment: thanks, but back to where we begun, still cant get the data and the screen is white again. =;/

Comment: before `switch`, try to `print(snapshot.data)` and see what you get (first you should get null because the future is still pending, but second time you should get your list).

Comment: okay, the data is there on the snapshot.data. Thanks, but how do i access this data? tired snapshot.data.index, and snapshot.data[index]

Comment: That's up to your data. do you see the `return` in `pegaDados`? this is what you get in `snapshot.data`.